# selenium cannot play video player

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, ubuntu-14.04, selenium-chromedriver

I have selenium tests running against chrome driver v 2.25. I have chrome v 54 installed on a ubuntu 14 server. I cannot get selenium tests to play video player that is in flash. Is there a plugin I need to install to get chrome on ubuntu to support flash?

The test loads a page with a video player and checks that there is a play button. I need to make sure that the server can load flash.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium cannot and will not automate embedded objects in any website.

This includes objects such as:

- Flash
- PDF
- Java Applets
- etc.

If you want to automate those, you will need to find a different tool.  Selenium is designed to automate websites, not external components of a website like flash.

Comment: selenium can and automates flash, just need extra plugin for flash (not Selenium)

Comment: it's not selenium at that point then :) you are using something else to automate the flash, so my statement still stands.  "Selenium cannot and will not automated embedded objects [like flash]"

Comment: it is. injecting Flex Pilot to flash makes tests work with flash exactly like with HTML DOM

Try this, if you interested :)
http://www.monsterdebugger.com/

Answer (score 0):

Got this working wit chrome 52+ and chromedriver 2.22+

At time of answer it works with chrome 55/2.27 - both 64 bit
all you need is add extra flag to chromedriver

`--ppapi-flash-path=chromedriver/chromedriver_linux64/libpepflashplayer.so`